# Is there way to insert variable in string? (html)

Tags: javascript, html

I have not learend any other program language and I started learning html today, I am making program that show random place on google map
google map link is this and   https://www.google.co.kr/maps/@36.3904052,127.331469,18.09z
I wnat to give link like   (https://www.google.co.kr/maps/@latitude,longitude,18.09z) this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>random palce</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#FAD0C9;">
    <div style="text-align:center">
        <strong>
            <p style="font-size: 70px; color:#6E6E6D">click the button</p>
        </strong>
        <script>
            var random1 = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (381601797 - 341601796)) + 341601796)/10000000;
            document.write( '<p>' + random1 + '</p>' );
            var random2 = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (1289677998 - 1262365489)) + 1262365489)/10000000;
            document.write( '<p>' + random2 + '</p>' );
         </script>
    <button onclick="location.href='https://www.google.co.kr/maps/'
    " style="width: 350px; height: 150px; font-size: 40px; background-color:#D64161; color:#364b44; border:none; ">random place</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

this is code I made
I want to edit <button onclick="location.href='https://www.google.co.kr/maps/'
this part to show link like (https://www.google.co.kr/maps/@latitude,longitude,18.09z)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: What you have inside `<script>` tags is JavaScript code.  You will be able to manipulate DOM elements when you learn enough of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the `onclick` event is Javascript, not html.

Then, you could use Template literals to insert variable in a string or an url. Also, I would not suggest you to write long Javascript code in `onclick`. Use `addEventListener` in script instead.

> Template literals are literals delimited with backticks (`), allowing embedded expressions called substitutions.

*I don't really know what the request url format for google map should look like, but directly write coordinates seems to be wrong. You have to figure it out by yourself.

```js
var random1 = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (381601797 - 341601796)) + 341601796) / 10000000;
document.write('<p>' + random1 + '</p>');
var random2 = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (1289677998 - 1262365489)) + 1262365489) / 10000000;
document.write('<p>' + random2 + '</p>');
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  location.href = `https://www.google.co.kr/maps/${random1+random2}`

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>random palce</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color:#FAD0C9;">
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <strong>
            <p style="font-size: 70px; color:#6E6E6D">click the button</p>
        </strong>

    <button style="width: 350px; height: 150px; font-size: 40px; background-color:#D64161; color:#364b44; border:none; ">random place</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @hyeonwoos, no problem:)